# Performing Action on every HTTP request (HttpServer)

Tags: java, grizzly

Is there anyway to perform some action every time there is an HTTP request on a grizzly `HttpServer`? Is there maybe an event to subscribe to or something?

I have tried subclassing the HttpHandler classes I need and overriding the `service()` method to do the work I need done, but one of the HttpHandler classes I need is declared final.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Grizzly, but  implementing a Filter wouldn't suit your use case? http://grizzly.java.net/filterchainfilters.html

Comment: My only problem with filters is that I can't find documentation anywhere explaining how to register them with a Grizzly server.

Comment: They have a example at https://grizzly.java.net/quickstart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out the [HttpServerProbe](https://github.com/GrizzlyNIO/grizzly-mirror/blob/2.3.x/modules/http-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/HttpServerProbe.java)

Probes may be registered with the HttpServerConfiguration object associated with your HttpServer instance.

Note that this may not be sufficient for your needs, in which case, it would be useful if you could provide details on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I just need to call a function every time an HTTP request is made. This looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!